# Time stamp to something readable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL Query that pulls exactly what I want but I am having trouble converting the time stamp to something readable. 
Here is what the Database outputs:
[image]

The timestamp should be **8/21/19 1:56 PM**

Here is the SQL Query I have right now:
Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

```
select MACHINE_ID as ZUM_TOOL_GROUP, LAST_VALUE as MISTI, LAST_TIMESTAMP  
from machine_signal
where machine_id like 'WSI%' and signal_id = 'RT2_COUNT'
order by ZUM_TOOL_GROUP ASC
```

Updated Picture with the new code:

[image]

New Code:

```
select MACHINE_ID as ZUM_TOOL_GROUP, LAST_VALUE as MISTI,
(date '1970-01-01' + LAST_TIMESTAMP / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) as time_date
from machine_signal
where machine_id like 'WSI%' and signal_id = 'RT2_COUNT'
order by ZUM_TOOL_GROUP ASC
```

The format works perfect but how do I get the timestamp correct? it should be 12:19 PM not 5:19PM

Answer (score 3):

This looks a Unix timestamp in milliseconds.  Here is a simple conversion:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + 1566402391000 / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
from dual;
```

If you want this in a particular timezone, you should offset it by the appropriate amount.

Comment: Hi, @Gordan thank you for the quick response but that will only do one timestamp. All the timestamps will be different and update every second. How can I do it for all values in this list? I just took a screenshot of one entry.

Comment: Just substitute your field name for the hard-coded value `1566402391000` in the example. The point is that the `LAST_TIMESTAMP` value you're seeing is the number of milliseconds since midnight on January 1, 1970.

Comment: Your query returns `2019-08-21 15:46:31` which is UTC time. In order to get the local time you should change it to something like `(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1566402391000 / 1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL` - but I have no idea where the 10 Minutes difference comes from.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff I used your recommended code and made the fix but for some reason, the time is off. Can you help me fix this small issue? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Dc5nipe . . . 10 minutes is really hard to explain.  1 hour would be a time stamp issue.  A second or two would be some adjustment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah I fixed my code but seem like it's off. Suppose to be 12:19 PM and it displays 5:19 PM. Can you look at my code above in the original problem statement? It's under new code with your recommendations.

Comment: @Dc5nipe . . . Add 5 hours to take into account your timezone . . . `+ '5' hour`.  I would be cautious, though, and leave the date/time in UTC format.  Things like daylight saving time can throw such adjustments off.